# java object designing help for ETL process

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing an ETL process where E ->Extractor : which is source and Transformer which transform content and Loader : is output where data to send/ store . I want all must be configurable means If currently source is file in future it can be database also same for output in future it can be database so class/object design should support this

```
I have following hierarchy of class 

public interface DataSource
{
public void init();
public Object getNextRecord();  
}

//I want to return generic result from getNextRecord 

public class FileSource implements DataSource
{
    public Object getNextRecord();
    {
        return file.readLine();     // one by one return file contains     
    }
}

public class SQLSource implements DataSource
{
    public Object getNextRecord();
    {
        Object[] result = new Object[colssize];
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
          result[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);  

        return result: // return one row as object array        
    }
}

public interface Loader
{
    public void addRecord(Object object);
}

public class fileLoader
{
    public void addRecord(Object object)
    {
        writeLineToFile((String) object);
    }
}

public class SQLLoader implements Loader
{
    public void addRecord(Object object)
    {
```

// problem here getting object array and don't know the tables details
            writeObjectToDB(object)
        }
    }
    public class CapitalizedFileTransformer {

```
    @Override
    public void transform(DataSource source, Loader loader)
    {

    // for file source and file loader this works like this
        String data = null;
        while ((data = (String) source.getNextRecord()) != null)
        {
            loader.addRecord(data.toUpperCase());
            loader.addRecord("\n");
        }
        source.close();
        loader.close();


    // but for sql source and sql loader I have problem
    because its returning object array also don't have table info here to which I have to insert and don't want to change code of CapitalizedFileTransformer 
    }
}

It will be great if anyone can help me to re-design this classes I want a source and loader and transformer to be generic i.e any file source should work with sql loader and with any transformer
```

Comment: If you don't have any limitations in your implementations check out Spring-Batch it does the similar thing, Read, Process, Write ;) It has out of the box readers, writers, transaction management, multi-threaded processing etc. Futher more your configuration related query will also be satisfied by Spring-batch as everything in this framework is configurable. only thing is "learning curve".

Comment: Yes I have limitation needs to do it using  only core java

Comment: well you can use properties file, specify your reader, writer and processor there, create/program to interfaces, that way you will add decoupling in your app. Apart from this use maven project. So you can manage dependencies easily, also configure database, filesystem related stuff in .properties file, read this properties file at the start up of app, keep the properties file in classpath or also provide an alternate way to find the location i.e. use java [PATH_LOC] of properties file. ;)